# problem with # character in java

Tags: javascript, struts, textarea, action

I have a problem, I'm getting a text from a textarea, from a jsp page, I'm using struts, all works fine, but, when I write a # character, the character # not arrive to the action so, I have tried too many things, but is not working, here you have some code that I'm using in the jsp page, is a javascript:

```
var detalle = document.getElementById("comentarioAgregado").value;

detalle = detalle.replace(/\r\n/g,"<br>");

location.href = "/SolicitudCredito/comentarioAction.do?comando=guardarParcial&comentarios="+detalle;
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u alerted detalle before the thrid

Comment: Yes, I have an alert on that part, and detalle displays "# ", but when I go to action, empty reaches

Answer (score 1):

You should sanitize your query string otherwise your site is vulnerable to injection attacks.

To solve this particular problem, simply replace `#` with `%23`:

```
detalle=detalle.replace(/#/g, "%23");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.... but when I put this piece of code, I write : "testing #", and the output string look like this : testing 5....not take the character %..... any idea!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: the user writes a text in a textarea, but when writes special characters, like # % &.... my program falls =(... because the special character arrive empty to the action, with an alert I checked that if the value is correct, and so is....the alert display "#", but in the action is empty...I hope I made myself understood.. thanks!!!!

Comment: But again, if you look at the fiddle, you can see that `#` gets replaced by `%35`. Your error is somewhere else in the code you don't show. How do you parse the query string in the destination page?

Comment: thanks.... I found the solution, %35 is a decimal code, but I test with a hex code, that is %23, and works fine... thank you so much...your answer lead me to this...look at this...http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html